# google app script error on executing the script (invalid argument)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, whatsapp, whatsapi

I am trying to send the message from google sheet to whatsapp but after executing the script it gives me an error:

Code:

```
function sendWhatsAppMessages() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var data = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var phoneNumber = data[i][0];
    var message = data[i][1];
    
    var encodedMessage = encodeURIComponent(message);
    var whatsappUrl = "https://wa.me/" + phoneNumber + "?text=" + encodedMessage;
    
    var options = {
      "method": "get",
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(whatsappUrl, options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

[image: google app script]

[image: google sheet]

Comment: Try URL Encoding with [EncodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 1):

When I saw the official document of "[How to use click to chat](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934/?helpref=uf_share)", it says as follows.

> Create your own link: Use https://wa.me/ where the  is a full phone number in international format. Omit any zeroes, brackets, or dashes when adding the phone number in international format.

> Examples:

> Use: `https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXXX`

> Don't use: `https://wa.me/+001-(XXX)XXXXXXX`

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var phoneNumber = data[i][0];
```

#### To:

```
var phoneNumber = data[i][0].replace(/^\+?0{1,}|[ ()+-]/g, "");
```

- By this modification, `+001-(XXX)XXXXXXX` is converted to `1XXXXXXXXXX`.

#### Reference:

- [How to use click to chat of WhatsApp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934/?helpref=uf_share)